# Matrix Rank in MATLAB

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matlab, matrix-rank

I want to find the rank of a matrix in Matlab. I wrote `gfrank(M)` in Matlab but Matlab  can not find the rank of the matrix. It say matrix is too large to convert to linear index. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's `gfrank(M)` in MATLAB.

In MATLAB you calculate the rank of a matrix $ M $ using `rank(M)`.
Namely using the [`rank()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rank.html) function.